# Unpack content of the reducer into combineReducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create a small application and figure out what's the best approach to organizing reducers in it. I want to load JSON from application state and want it to look like this:

```json
{
  "fruits": [
    {"apple": 1},
    {"banana": 2},
    {"avocado": 1}
  ],
  "vagetables": [
    {"onion": 1},
    {"beetroot": 2},
    {"celeriac": 3}
  ],
"milk": "1 bottle",
"sugar": "1 kg",
"flour": "1 kg"
}
```

The application has 2 reducers that return lists for fruits and vegetables, but there is also a third one that returns an object with all other fields like milk, sugar, and so on. And I want to understand if it is possible to somehow unpack the contents of this reducer into a root reducer:

```js
//fruitReducer.js
const initialState = {}

export const fruitReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_FRUIT:
             return {...state, [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value }
  }
}


//vagetablesReducer.js
const initialState = {}

export const vagetablesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_VAGETABLE:
             return {...state, [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value }
  }
}

//otherGoodsReducer.js
const initialState = {}

export const otherGoodsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_OTHER_GOOD:
             return {...state, [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value }
  }
}


//rootReducer.js
rootReducer = combineReducers({
      vagetables: vagetableReducer,
      fruits: fruitReducer,
      //need to unpack other products here
})
```

I would also like to figure out what is good practice in this case. I just have a lot of identical inputs for milk, sugar, etc. and it was convenient for me to process them with one reducer. But now I cannot figure out how to form a JSON suitable for me (It doesn't work for me if a separate key will be created for these objects.).

Comment: Your state doesn’t need to be in the same shape as the JSON that you want to render.  You can use a selector to reformat it.  It probably makes sense to have a flatter structure where fruits and vegetables are stored alongside each other and handled by the same reducer.  For each ingredient you would have fields like “quantity” and some sort of “type” which is either “fruit” or “vegetable”.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, it is possible to combine the three reducers in the way that you want, but you need to write your own function to do it rather than using combineReducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like this structure, but here's how you would do it.  You can't use `combineReducers` so you need to write your own function to combine them.  It would look like:

```
const rootReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    const {vagetables, fruits, ...otherGoods} = state;
    return {
        vagetables: vagetablesReducer(vagetables, action),
        fruits: fruitsReducer(fruits, action),
        ...otherGoodsReducer(otherGoods, action)
    }
}
```

But this is really unecessary.  If you store all of the other ingredients in a property called `otherGoods` then you can use `combineReducers`

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({
      vagetables: vagetableReducer,
      fruits: fruitReducer,
      otherGoods: otherGoodsReducer
})
```

When you want to get the ingredients in the format that your app expects you can use a selector.

```
const formatState = (state) => {
    const {vagetables, fruits, otherGoods} = state;
    return {
        vagetables,
        fruits,
        ...otherGoods
    }
};
```

This will return the JSON that you expect.  The `...` spread operator before `...otherGoods` puts each element of `otherGoods` at the root of the returned object.

**Edit:**

In my opinion, the best structure for this data set has only one reducer, especially since you mentioned wanting to reduce code repetition.  You should be able to have general actions like "ADD_INGREDIENT", "INCREASE_QUANTITY", "SET_QUANTITY", etc. which apply the same way to all ingredients whether it is a fruit, vegetable, or other.

I recommend a state which looks like this:

```
const state = {
    apple: {
        quantity: 1,
        category: "fruit",
    },
    banana: {
        quantity: 2,
        category: "fruit",
    },
    avocado: {
        quantity: 1,
        category: "fruit",
    },
    onion: {
        quantity: 1,
        category: "vegetable",
    },
    beetroot: {
        quantity: 2,
        category: "vegetable",
    },
    celeriac: {
        quantity: 3,
        category: "vegetable",
    },
    milk: {
        quantity: 1,
        units: "bottle",
        category: "other",
    },
    sugar: {
        quantity: 1,
        units: "kg",
        category: "other",
    },
    flour: {
        quantity: 1,
        units: "kg",
        category: "other",
    }
};
```

`quantity` is always a `number`, so it's easy to do mathematical operations like add and subtract.

`units` is an optional string which you would combine with quantity to get strings like "1 kg"

`category` is one of "fruit", "vegetable", or "other".  You can use this field to filter or group your ingredients.

You could choose to include `name` as a property on each ingredient even though it is the same as the `key`.  I like doing this because then you just need to use `Object.values` and you'll get a complete object which includes the name.  This makes it very easy to filter, sort, etc.

You could also key by a unique numeric `id` for each ingredient instead of by `name`, in which case you would have `name` as a property.